# foundation icon font :hover styling not working, sass/css

Tags: html, css, sass, icons, zurb-foundation

So i'm using foundation with foundation 3 font icons and im trying to make the icon color change on hover in sass:

```
#icons{

 a:hover{
   i{
   color: darken($primary-color, 20%);
   }

 }
}
```

heres my html:

```
     <div class="container1">
       <div id="icons" class="row">
        <div class="medium-4 large-4 text-center column adjust">
         <a href="#"><i id="promotional" class="fi-calendar"></i></a>
```

I can get the icon color changed, and linked but nothing happens on hover.
I'm kind of stumped on it and im sure im doing something wrong but haven't figured it out. Can anyone help on it?

Comment: thanks i got it working i had an extra curly bracelet that needed to be removed, thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My syntax was off, be sure all curly bracers are closed and lined up properly